# customize navigation to seperate button so that it can access to different screen

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have created a separate button widget so that I can access it to all other screens where ever I needed by just changing a name and navigation, but I don't know how to add navigation to customize  name for different screens

```dart
class GlowingButton extends StatefulWidget {
    final Color color1;
    final Color color2;

    const GlowingButton({
    Key key,
    this.color1 = Colors.brown,
    this.color2 = Colors.white10,
    this.buttonName,
    this.routeName,
    }) : super(key: key);
    final String buttonName;
    final  routeName;
    @override
    _GlowingButtonState createState() => _GlowingButtonState();
    }

    class _GlowingButtonState extends State<GlowingButton> {
    var glowing = true;
    var scale = 1.0;
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapUp: (val)async {
        setState(() {
          glowing = false;
          scale = 1.0;
        });
      },
      onTapDown: (val)async {
        setState(() {
          glowing = true;
          scale = 1.1;
        });
       onTapDown: (val) async {
        setState(() {
          glowing = true;
          scale = 1.1;
        });
        await Future.delayed(
          Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        );
        await Navigator.pushNamed(context,  MyRoute.(widget.routeName));
        setState(
          () {},
        );
      },
}
```

[image]

Comment: In your case, I prefer using callBackMethod.

Comment: can you include `MyRoute`

Comment: how can you please elaborate yourself using example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function on `GlowingButton`

```dart
class GlowingButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color1;
  final Color color2;
  final Function onTapDown;


.......

  onTapDown: (val) async {
        setState(() {
          glowing = true;
          scale = 1.1;
        });
        // await Future.delayed(
        //   Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        // );
        // await Navigator.pushNamed(context,  MyRoute.(widget.routeName));

        await widget.onTapDown();
        setState(
          () {},
        );
      },
```

and use

```
  GlowingButton(onTapDown: ()async{},...)
```

Also, you can pass full `routeName` and use the way you did

`await Navigator.pushNamed(context,  "${widget.fullRouteName}");` // if you have something to add on `routeName` follow `value${variable}`.

Does it solve in your case?

Comment: Glad to help you out.